# In TCPView, why does the svchost.exe process need to listen on so many TCP and UDP ports

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, svchost

Looking at [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) I can see over 25 svchost processes using TCP and UDP ports. If these svchost processes are the various services required by Windows, then why would so many be using the network?

Comment: +1. Good question. Windows is chatty. svchosts obscures what is really going on.

Comment: Each svchost process is a different service. You can use Process Explorer to check which services are using which ports

Comment: a good question is why can't the one process listen on the various ports?  I think openssh's sshd.exe may do that one process but able to listen on many ports.  Perhaps it's because the programs are all different e.g. different DLL files and using svchost to communicate through

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svchost):

> In the Windows NT family of operating systems, svchost.exe (Service
>   Host, or SvcHost) is a system process which hosts multiple Windows
>   services. Its executable image, %SystemRoot%\System32\Svchost.exe
>   or %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\Svchost.exe (for 32-bit services running on
>   64-bit systems) runs in multiple instances, each hosting one or more
>   services. It is essential in the implementation of so-called shared
>   service processes, where a number of services can share a process in
>   order to reduce resource consumption.

So, is expected that you have a lot of Windows processes running over a svhost.exe. Many of them just use TCP/IP ports(sockets) to [inter-processes comunication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Main_IPC_methods) over localhost. That's why you can see a lot of network traffic over svhost.exe.

Additionally you could also [find which Windows Service is running over svhost.](http://www.happysysadm.com/2010/11/svchostexe.html) I run "tasklist /svc" command on my computer and it returned me the dependencies between svhost and some running Windows Services:

[image]

Comment: Aren't all these windows processes using TCP for inter-process communication creating a zillion security holes, since now every one of those processes becomes a potential target for a hacker? In addition what is the cost of setting up a TCP connection as opposed to just using a pipe?